# Reversing queue only using helper queue and queue functions (no stack or anything)

Tags: java, interface, queue, reverse

I dont understand this. If we start with:

> | a | b | c | d |

reverse it using this, I get:

> | b | c | d | a |

It only seems to reverse the first letter, can someone break it down by line please, so I can see where im getting confused. Thanks!

`Q` is the queue we want to reverse using a helper queue.

```
public static void reverseQueue(Queue Q)
{
  Queue q = new Queue(); //helper queue
  while (!Q.isEmpty())
  {
    for(int i = 1; i <= Q.size()-1; i++) //move last element to the first
       Q.enqueue(Q.dequeue());
    q.enqueue(Q.dequeue()); //move it to q
  }
  while(!q.isEmpty())
    Q.enqueue(q.dequeue());
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: [I downvoted because there appears to have been no effort to debug the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score 0):

Your method is *okayish*, yet, there are some pretty major flows:

- To comply with the super interface `Queue` as your argument, you should use its implemented methods - `add` and `remove` respectively (given Queue is not some other implementation).
- **You cannot instantiate Interface or abstract class!**
- You don't check for an empty or 1-sized queue, before anything else.
- If you are not obliged to use queues only, look for more powerful structure as a helper.
- Parameters in Java should start with small-case letter.
- **Java is always 0-indexed** an should better remain so.

The following goes in linear time:

```
    public static void reverseQueue(Queue<Object> q) {
        if (q.isEmpty() || q.size() == 1)
            return; //nothing happens here

        int s = q.size();
        Object[] helper = new Object[s];

        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
            helper[s - 1 - i] = q.remove();

        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
            q.add(helper[i]);
    }
```

If you insist on using queues - take away *your* code, but instead of trying to instantiate an interface, use some implementing class e.g. LinkedList as helper.